# Getting value of an element in an array in Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have been stuggling to make a variable equal to the value to a specific element in an array and I was hoping someone had a suggestion. I am trying to get the value in cell E5 in this case

```
  async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext){
   let workbook = context.workbook;
   let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
   let sheet1 = worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
   var currentMonth = 1 

   var months = sheet1.getRange("E5:AD5");
   months.load("values")
   await context.sync();
   monthValue = months[1][currentMonth].value
   console.log(monthValue.values)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm not fluent with Office Scripts but isn't `context.sync` a function? If so you miss the parenthesis and it should look like `await context.sync()`.

Comment: Hi Moutah, sorry i just made a typo in the code, you are correct. However the main issue is how to get the value of the element in the array I am after, in this case the value in cell E5

Comment: Ah I think I see now, let me write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Change `months[1][currentMonth].value` to `months.values[0][currentMonth]`.

**Details**

Two issues here. The first is that to access the loaded values, you need to write `months.values` as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges#get-values-text-or-formulas

The second is that with `getRange("E5:AD5")`, you're getting a single line of values. `months.values` will thus hold values in the form of an array (rows) containing an array (cols) containing the values. Something like:

```
[
  ["cell E5", "cell F5", "cell G5", ...]
]
```

So one line, many columns.

But by doing `months[1]` you're trying to access the *second* line of this set. The first line is `months[0]`.

Same goes with the columns, the first column is index `0`. So the value of the first cell of your set is `months.values[0][0]`.

Comment: Hey Moutah, thanks for kindly taking time out of your day to answer this. Your answer makes perfect sense however when I try `months[0][0].values` I get an error message stating `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'months[0][0]')` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `{m_contextBase: Object, m_objectPath: Object, m_context: Object, _IsTracked: true, m_isNull: false…}` with various dropdown arrows which lead to the array values all being listed correctly. if change it to `console.log(months.values)` then all the array values are listed correctly, so that isnt a problem I dont think. Its accessing the specific element that seems to be the difficulty

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. Found some documentation and it looks like the `.value` is misplaced. Answer updated.